# How to compare the probability of the following situation?

Tags: probability, statistics

A letter is drawn 1000 times from A, A, A, R, B, I.

1) You win a dollar if the number of A's among the draws is 10 times or more above the expected number.

2) You win a dollar if the number of B's among the draws is 10 times or more above the expected number.

Intuitively, I feel the answer is A because we have a better chance pick A. 
But I am not quite sure about the standard way to think about it. Could someone suggest a direction?

Comment: Do you mean "10 times or more" as in $x+10$ or as in $10x$?

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability of drawing an A? $\frac1{2}.$

What is the probability of drawing a B? $\frac1{6}.$

$$ $$

What is the expected number of A's in $1000$ draws? $500.$

What is the expected number of B's in $1000$ draws? $166 \frac2{3}.$

$$ $$

What is the $10$ times the expected number of A's in $1000$ draws? $5000.$

What is the $10$ times the expected number of B's in $1000$ draws? $1666 \frac2{3}.$

$$ $$

Now you can answer these:

What is the probability of getting $5000$ A's or more in $1000$ draws?

What is the probability of getting $1667$ B's or more in $1000$ draws?

$$ $$

Hint: Don't take either of these bets!